# Android - Disable onClick highlight for one group in expandable list?

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an `ExpandableListView` backed by an implementation of `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.  The first group in the list functions as a header and is not expandable.  I've set `isChildSelectable()` to return false for this group and everything's functioning normally.  However, when the user clicks on this non-expandable group, the UI still highlights the row.  This is a confusing and unnecessary visual cue that I'd like to eliminate.

I can't set android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" on the ExpandableListView itself, because I *do* want the other list items to be highlighted upon click and expansion.

Is it possible to suppress click highlighting for that first group (only)?

Comment: I'm struggling with this one too, if anyone knows how to do this please answer here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893253/android-disable-single-item-highlighting-in-expandablelistview

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the individual parent view's `OnClickListener` to `null` from `getGroupView()`.

```
View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    convertView.setOnClickListener(null);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

just add this line on your expand list on XML file